# Java code generation and execution at runtime, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, code-generation, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on a project at my uni using Java. As we reached a state of development where we want to run a few benchmarks on a dedicated benchmark grid (offered by the uni) we encountered some problems.

The program generates code itself and executes it at runtime (we precompile some code at initialization), this is needed because of some optimizations which we made.

Now, if we submit the code into the job queue and run it via "ant Main" the following error occurs:

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.tools.ToolProvider
 [java]    at propnet.PropNetComputations.compilePropnet(PropNetComputations.java:72)
 [java]    at propnet.PropNetStateMachine.initialize(PropNetStateMachine.java:145)
 [java]    at propnet.PropNetStateMachine.initialize(PropNetStateMachine.java:109)
 [java]    at statemachine.StateMachineGamer.metaGame(StateMachineGamer.java:177)
 [java]    at core.request.StartRequest.process(StartRequest.java:47)
 [java]    at core.GamePlayer.run(GamePlayer.java:82)
 [java]    at core.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

The compilations seems to run through without any problems, but the execution seems to fail because of NoClassDefFoundError. At first, we thought this may be a version problem so we tested various Java versions (sun 1.6x, 1.7x and openjdk 1.6x) but the version itself doesn't seem to be the problem.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: What is your classpath setting in your Ant build, and what is the host operating system for the benchmark grid?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using JDK instead of JRE to run your application. As far as I know JRE doesn't include `javax.tools.*` classes but JDK does. You can also try to add `tools.jar` to classpath manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are two paths I would try to solve this issue, in this order.

1. Is the VM where the code is generated the same VM the code was executed?  The runtime is saying it tried to run that class, but when it looked for it, it could not be found.  You may be missing a dependency you compiled with, but the dependency is not in the classpath of where the code is executing.
2. This is less likely, but I've run into this issue.  Sometimes there may be two of the same dependencies in your classpath.  You may have also compiled the code with a different dependency than you are running it on.  They may be named the same, but could be different versions.  This can cause the class not found error if the dependency has changed it's contents.  If this is the case, you lucked out, because usually much harder to track down errors occur from this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFound simply means that there's some class in the program or library which depends on a class which isn't present in the class path. If you don't reference this class directly from your program, compilation will go ok.

In your case you are probably missing tools.jar in your classpath. Add it and everything will work fine.